# ADO.NET Best Practices for Connection and DataAdaptor Object Scope - follow-up

Tags: ado.net

I had the exact same question that was asked by Mark Lansdown some time ago.  [Mark's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594053/ado-net-best-practices-for-connection-and-dataadaptor-object-scope)

The answers in that thread were somewhat helpful but left me still extremely puzzled; particularly as it relates to the recommended practice of employing "using" blocks.

The first answer seemed to indicate that the Connection object and the DataAdapter object should be created within using blocks...

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("my_connection_string"))
using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * from Employees", conn))
{
  adapter.Fill(dt);    
}
```

Thus, the DataTable object is retained but both the DataAdapter and Connection object go out of scope the instant the table is filled.

Yet a follow-on answer indicated that the DataAdapter Object should be retained.  That makes perfect sense to me as it does appear to me that the DataAdapter was designed with handling multiple commands in mind.

So this leaves me with multiple questions:
BTW, I am using vb.net with SQL Server

Question 1)  In order to retain the DataAdapter object doesn't that mean I cannot create it with a using block?

Question 2) In order to create an instance of a DataAdapter don't I need an instance of a Connection object which would make it impractical to create the Connection object with a using block?

How would I implement the using blocks in code like this?

```
Private Class frmMain

  Dim adapter as SqlDataAdapter
  Dim conn as SqlConnection

  Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    
    conn = new SqlConnection("My_Connection_String")
    adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Employees", conn)
    
    adapter.fill(MyDataSet, MyTableName)

  End Sub
  
  Private Sub SaveButtton_Click(sender as Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveButton.Click
    adapter.Update(MyTableName)
  End Sub
End Class
```

I have seen a bunch of sample code for all this on msdn and every sample code I saw incorporated using blocks but always created a table via code and performed updates via code all inside the using blocks which seems to me like it could never work in the real world.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a follow-on answer indicated that the DataAdapter Object should be retained...
>
> Question 1) In order to retain the DataAdapter object doesn't that mean I cannot create it with a using block?

No. The response is flawed. Remember, `DataAdpater` was in .Net 1.0. At this time there was no good way to dispose your objects, so you did the best you could. `Using` blocks and good `IDisposable` support were added for .Net 2.0, and this caused a change in direction for how things should be done. Yes, a DataAdapter can have different kinds of queries, and has the ability to support longer lifetimes if that's really want you want, but it's rarely a good choice anymore to use it that way.

If you really want, you can still create another DataAdapter later on if you need it for the different type of query, or you can use `ExecuteNonQuery()` for things like DELETE, INSERT, and UPDATE. But if you want the framework to do more of that kind of work for you, you should really go for a full ORM. If you want to write your own `SELECT` statements in code, you're usually better off also writing your own INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE (etc) statements by hand, as well (and be sure to use parameterized queries!).

> Question 2) In order to create an instance of a DataAdapter don't I need an instance of a Connection object which would make it impractical to create the Connection object with a using block?
>
> How would I implement the using blocks in code like this?

Don't write code like that. Rather than repeat myself I'll link to a previous answer explaining why:

> https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/142065/creating-database-connections-do-it-once-or-for-each-query/398790#398790

But the short version is an ADO.Net connection object is a thin wrapper around much "heavier" and more expensive items in a connection pool. When you try to re-use a connection throughout a class or application, you gain efficiency in the relatively cheap wrapper at the expense of the much larger real underlying connections. You really are much better off creating a new connection each time. Only the connection string should be preserved for re-use.

> every sample code I saw incorporated using blocks but always created a table via code and performed updates via code all inside the using blocks which seems to me like it could never work in the real world.

I assure you, it works very well. Again, if you don't like it, maybe you're looking for a full ORM like EntityFramework.